# STFT computational burden

Tags: spectrogram

1. I have a signal with length of $N$.
2. The sampling frequency is $f_s$.
3. Window size is $w$
4. The noverlap size is set to $m$.
5. And $nfft$ is selected for frequency resolutions.

I am running a STFT with matlab `spectrogram` function.

```
[S,F,T,P]=spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,nfft,fs)
```

- what is the effect of *nfft* , $f_s$ and  noverlap on STFT
  computational burden?
- what is computation complexity of STFT with these parameters size?
  {in term of big `O()` }

Note: The `FFT` computational complexity for a signal with length of $N$ is $Nlog(N)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of FFTs is roughly N/(w-m). An fft costs you nfft*log2(nfft) so the total is proportional to N/(w-m)*nfft*log2(nfft).

A typical application would make nfft = w and m = w/2, so this would come out to be proportional to N*log2(nfft). So it's proportional to the length or you data set (obviously) and the log of the FFT size.